# cdk LS failed because it doesn't find the app

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm running the sample-app but seems it doesn't work anymore

> .env) [cdk-workshop]gdm$ cdk ls
>   CDK CLI >= 1.10.0 is required to interact with this app
>   (.env) [cdk-workshop]gdm$

Why?

the code is exactly https://cdkworkshop.com/30-python/20-create-project/100-cdk-init.html

Answer (score 0):

the problem was my ckd version(1.9.0)
I've updated and now it works